# Array de Bytes x Stream

Tags: c#, web-service, wcf

Estou desenvolvendo um serviço em WCF que vai converter arquivos.
Farei o upload e depois o download dos arquivos. Os arquivos não são grandes.

O que é preferível no caso do envio e recebimento, retornar um array de bytes ou um stream ? Alguma outra classe mais especializada ?

Answer (score 1):

**No site da MSDN**, a definição para a classe Stream

> Fornece uma forma genérica de ver uma sequencia de bytes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

### Análise

Porém, discordo deles quanto o que está resumido nessa simples frase acima. Stream, imagine um **fluxo**, que pode ser ter orientação unidirecional ou bidirecional. Array de bytes está intimamente ligada a dados primitivos, é bem próximo, entretanto com Stream você ganha mais recursos e um melhor gerenciamento por parte do .NET.

---

### Cenário

Você mencionou que esses arquivos não são grandes, eu entendi que sua ideia é passar todo o arquivo para um array de bytes, mesmo que não sejam grandes, não seria o correto. Trabalhando com Streams você garante mais autonomia ao GC para cuidar dessa parte para você e garantir desempenho ao seu serviço, também podendo usar a memória virtual. Pelo fato de você estar no lado de um servidor, você tem que garantir desempenho e baixo consumo.

---

### Stream vs. Array Bytes

1. Flexibilidade para manipulação.
2. Gerenciamento de memória mais autônomo para o GC.
3. Funções que caracterizam um objeto mais bem definido.
4. Async.
5. Propriedades úteis e objetivas.
6. Wrapper para Thread-Safe.
7. Disposable.
8. Buffer também pode estar localizada na memória virtual p/ arquivos.

---

### Informações adicionais

Tudo foi baseado em experiências que tive, pode ter mais detalhes que posso ter esquecido.
Deixarei um link abaixo que é simples e objetivo quanto a Operações Stream em WCF.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36973/Stream-Operation-in-WCF

Answer (score 0):

Realmente depende em como está criado a sua sistema. É importante saber que um stream não significa que os dados tem chegado no computador. Parece bastante como IEnumerable em que as vezes os dados estão no memoria do computador, mas também poderia representar dados que você não tem ainda.

Em fim, eu ia retornar um Stream porque quando são retornados você ainda pode escolher quando e como pegar os dados no Stream (mas de novo, depende na sistema). Tem nada errado com um array de bytes, mas um Stream seria mais correto.

---

Exemplo de um Stream que faz isto (não é WCF): https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Depois que você tiver obtido NetworkStream, chame o método de Write para enviar dados para o host remoto. Chame o método de Read para receber os dados que chegam host remoto